# Why am I getting the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"?

Tags: swift

In the following code, I'm trying to check a domain name for a match on some search text.  The search text is in the variable `searchText` but Xcode is giving me an error stating:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

The caret is pointing at the first character of `linkRange.location != NSNotFound` in the last line.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and the error message is not very helpful

```
// search domain name
let linkText: NSString = dict["link"]!
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: linkText as String)!
let domain = url.host
let linkRange = domain!.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
let foundInLink = linkRange.location != NSNotFound
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rangeOfString` gives you back a `Range` not an `NSRange`, and it doesn't have a `location` property. So you should have to do somethink like this in the last line:

```
let foundInLink = linkRange != nil
```